# Ruby on Rails allow multiple clicks for link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and have found myself stumped.

I am trying to create a link_to item in my view that will not be disabled after being clicked once.  It's a page listing people's names and their attendance.  The names are colored red if absent and green if present and I'd like the user to be able to toggle the attendance more than once for each person.

Here is the code for my view and controller (note I am using websockets here as well to update the coloring of the button after being clicked):

index.html.erb:

```
    <div id="reader-attendance-<%= member.id %>">
      <% if member.present == true %>
          <%= link_to member.last_name.upcase, attendance_path(:id => member.id, :present => false), remote: true, class: "btn btn-outline-success btn-14" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to member.last_name.upcase, attendance_path(:id => member.id, :present => true), remote: true, class: "btn btn-outline-danger btn-14" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

controller.rb:

```
  def attendance
    member = Member.find(params[:id])
    if(params[:present] == 'true')
      member.present = true
    else
      member.present = false
    end
    member.save
    vote_member = VoteMember.where(member_name: member.display_name)[0]
    if vote_member.vote_type == 'Absent'
      vote_member.vote_type = ''
      vote_member.save
    end
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      'attendance_channel',
      {
        member_id: member.id,
        present: params[:present],
        vote_member_id: vote_member.id,
        total_abs: Member.where(present: false).count(),
        member_name: member.last_name.upcase
      }
    )
  end
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. I've read that you can add an option to config so that the disable option is turned off as follows:
   Rails.application.configure do
   config.action_view.automatically_disable_submit_tag = false
   end
   The it seems like this is not supported, however, for the link_to tag and is only supported for button_to
2. I added the content in #1 to config and then I've tried the button_to option as follows with no success.  I have a feeling it's the way that I've passed the parameters in here:

```
  <%=button_to member.last_name.upcase ,:action => :attendance, :id => member.id, :present => false, remote: true, class: "btn btn-outline-success btn-14" %>
```

I am working with the following versions:

Rails 6.1.4.1
Ruby 3.0.1

Thanks in advance!  Please let me know if other info would be helpful.

Comment: On a side note I would really avoid using the column/attribute name `present` as it will potentially clash with the `Object#present?` method declared by ActiveSupport which is used everywhere in the framework. `attending` is a better alternative. Doing boolean comparison is also extremely unrubyeske. Bad: `thing.other_thing == true`. Good:  `thing.other_thing?`

Comment: As for the rest of issue - the solution here is most likely to just write your own click handler that does what you want it to do. Don't hook everything onto Rails UJS - especially since its getting axed in Rails 7.

Comment: @max Thank you so much!  The feedback is very valuable since I am so new to Ruby!  When you say write your own click handler - is there a "ruby on rails" way to do this?  I ask b/c I want to try to follow the ruby on rails best practices as I learn.  Thanks again.

Comment: Not really. Rails UJS and Turbolinks and now Stimulus and Turbo came out of Basecamp and where always propular in the Rails community and have shipped with Rails by default. However its just one way to build apps and in my opinion its a horrible way to learn AJAX and javascript basics as the whole approach with Server Side Concerns makes the separation of concerns between the front and back end very muddy.